# Passing a parameter in CFHTTP URL string

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am using `cfhttp` to post a series of user supplied parameters to an API. I am passing all of the parameters with `<cfhttparam>` except one: `{myID}`. Since the `{myID}` value will also be supplied by the user, I am wondering how can I make sure it gets passed inside the URL string?

```
<cfhttp url="http://abc.xyz.com/webservice/{myID}/add/multiple" 
       method="POST" result="returnStruct" >

    <cfhttpparam name="Accept" type="header" value="application/json" />        
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="datetime" value="#datetime#" />
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="authorization" value="#authorization#" /> 
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="myAPI" value="1" />
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="param1" value="1000" />
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="param2" value="myname@email.com" />
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="param3" value="2" />
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="param4" value="Tester" />
</cfhttp>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client aplication should have the user's data from a previous request, if you pass it like 
`http://abc.xyz.com/webservice/user_id/add/multiple` the server assumes that `user_id` is the parameter you call `{myID}`

Good luck

Comment: So, do I need to include the `myID` in the form of `cfhttparam` tag?

Comment: no, that would be redundant, just pass it through URL, like `http://abc.xyz.com/webservice/123456/add/multiple` where `123456` is the user's id

Comment: you can get the id from the url, no need to pass it for param

Comment: Okay, Thanks a lot. One more question, is it a good idea to pass the `ID` to the URL? Or one should use it in `cfhttparam` tag instead of using it in URL? Which approach is popular and why? Thanks

Comment: Could anyone answer my question?

Comment: please use the param of typ=" URL" which is better approach